# My first JavaScript. Any errors?

Tags: javascript

Good Sunday morning!

After fiddling around with some JavaScript this weekend, I finally wrote my first script. It is a Tooltip generator. It works great in FF 3 + 3.5, IE 6 + 7, Safari 4, Chrome 2 + 3, and Opera 9 + 10.

Before putting my new code into production, I thought I'd ask if you see any glaring problems -- or maybe it's perfect as-is? (Lol)

JSLint.com reports:

```
Error:

Problem at line 10 character 15: 'e' is already defined.

    var e = window.event;

Implied global: window 10, document 19,20,22,24,33,35,41,43,49,55
```

Here is my code (apologies in advance if you don't like my code style):

```
function getmouseposition( e )
{
    var offx = 22;
    var offy = 14;
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;

    if ( !e )
    {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    if ( e.pageX || e.pageY )
    {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if ( e.clientX || e.clientY )
    {
        posx = e.clientX
               + document.body.scrollLeft
               + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY
               + document.body.scrollTop
               + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    if ( document.getElementById )
    {
        var tooltip = document.getElementById( 'tooltip' );

        tooltip.style.left = ( posx + offx ) + 'px';
        tooltip.style.top = ( posy + offy ) + 'px';
    }
}

function tooltip_on( text )
{
    if( !document.getElementById( 'tooltip' ) )
    {
        var span = document.createElement( 'span' );

        span.id = 'tooltip';
        span.style.display = 'none';
        span.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';

        document.body.appendChild( span );
    }
    var tooltip = document.getElementById( 'tooltip' );

    tooltip.innerHTML = text;
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
    tooltip.style.position = 'absolute';

    document.onmouseover = getmouseposition;
    // document.onmousemove = getmouseposition;
}

function tooltip_off()
{
    document.getElementById( 'tooltip' ).style.display = 'none';
}
```

EDIT:

I'm also wondering, what does this line say (in layman's terms ) in the `getmouseposition function`:

```
if ( document.getElementById )
```

Comment: Hey Jeff, why don't you use the title attribute?

Comment: Probably because he can't style them using CSS.

Comment: I figured this was the case. But without further context I wasn't sure.

Comment: The 'if (document.getElementById)' is checking if the document object has a member called getElementById, if it doesn't it'll get 'undefined' so the condition will become 'if (undefined)', and the undefined data type supports conversion to boolean, which it will return as false.. on the other hand, if the member exists it will get the object, and I believe by default objects convert to a boolean value true.. basically, it is checking if the browser supports the function 'getElementById' so that it can then attempt to use it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Wish I could accept more than one answer, because they're all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That jslint error means that the variable `e` is already defined within the scope of the `getmouseposition` function by virtue of being an argument to said function.  There is no need to redeclare it, so just remove the `var` from that line.

Second, explicitly accessing properties of the `window` and `document` objects is pretty standard. I wouldn't change that part of your code. Not sure why jslint even mentions those lines.

Very picky style police will complain about spaces just within parentheses:

```
// Most do this:
function myFunction(param){
   // Statement 1
   // Statement 2
   // Statement 3
}

// Not this
function myFunction( param )
{
   // Statement 1
   // Statement 2
   // Statement 3
}
```

And very *very* picky style dorks will tell you to use a single var declaration at the top of your function:

```
// Do this
function getmouseposition(e){
    var offx = 22,
        offy = 14,
        posx = 0,
        posy = 0;


// Not this
function getmouseposition(e)
{
    var offx = 22;
    var offy = 14; 
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
```

Lastly, most style-conscious javascript programmers will use camel case for functions, so `getMousePosition` instead of `getmouseposition`

My opinion is that, besides removing the `var` declaration as I suggested at the top, your code is quite readable and decent style, as long as you stick to the format consistently.

Answer (score 4):

for the error : since `e` is an argument of your function, it already exists, so you don't need to declare it, just assign a value to it if its null or undefined.

Just remove the "`var`" part of the concerned line :

```
if ( !e ) e = window.event;
```

Comment: So just to be clear, I should change "if ( !e ) { var e = window.event; }" to just "if ( !e ) e = window.event;"?

Comment: Note if you remove the curly braces like the example, jslint will complain, it enforces you don't drop the statement block braces.

Comment: considering what meandmycode said you (Jeff) should change "`if ( !e ) { var e = window.event; }`" to "`if ( !e ) { e = window.event; }`".

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**  There are always errors, even if nobody spots them.

However, in this particular case the report you gave is right.  Where you have:

```
var e = window.event;
```

That's creating a *new* `e` variable, not replacing the `e` parameter you've already defined.  Change it to:

```
e = window.event;
```

Comment: So just to be clear, I should change "if ( !e ) { var e = window.event; }" to just "e = window.event;"? Someone said something very similar below.

Comment: You should replace precisely the line `var e = window.event;` with precisely the line `e = window.event;`  p4bl0 recommends exactly the same thing, but also removes your braces for stylistic reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you follow the function name convention. It makes life a lot easier for those who will maintain your code.

```
function myMethodName(myParam) {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Voted back up for karma. BTW, someone voted my whole question down. Boooooo! Lol

Answer (score 1):

You have `e` as a parameter to your function and also declared via `var e =`  inside your function. When a parameter is passed to your function it already exists as that name, and declaring a variable with the same name will cause an error. I would change either the name of the variable declared, the name of the parameter or assign it properly if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the JSLint problem related to the `implied global... document` check the assume a browser option. The syntax looks good, except I would try to declare all your variables using a single var command and a comma-separated list at the top of your function. It's a bit more efficient that way and easier to `maintain`/`read`.

You are doing well for your first attempt and I hope this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your edit, that if is checking if the `getElementById` function is available, in now days, it's safe to assume that this function is available.

Rather than checking for the function, you could check if the element was found:

```
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');

if (tooltip) {
  tooltip.style.left = ( posx + offx ) + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = ( posy + offy ) + 'px';
}
```

Your `getmouseposition` function, can be simplified:

```
function getmouseposition( e ) { 
  var offx = 22, 
      offy = 14, 
      posx = 0, 
      posy = 0, tooltip; 

  e = e || window.event; 
  posx = e.pageX || (e.clientX 
                    + document.body.scrollLeft 
                    + document.documentElement.scrollLeft); 

  posy = e.pageY || (e.clientY  
                    + document.body.scrollTop 
                    + document.documentElement.scrollTop); 

  if (tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')) { 
    tooltip.style.left = ( posx + offx ) + 'px'; 
    tooltip.style.top = ( posy + offy ) + 'px'; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if ( document.getElementById )`

This check is to detect if the function getElementById is defined for the document object for the browser currently used. If the user uses a browser that does not support this function, you don't want to get an error in the browser, but rather handle the case.